openssl_pkcs12_export with legacy option
Is there a way for openssl_pkcs12_export to use legacy algorithms like command line openssl -legacy do? Maybe there are some openssl.cnf directives that force legacy algorithms for PKCS#12 export globally?

Currently, I'm using this call to the openssl command line tool as workaround, but I'm very interested in a more elegant solution since most software (e.g. Windows and iOS cert store) still only supports the legacy format.
function openssl_pkcs12_export_legacy(
    OpenSSLAsymmetricKey|OpenSSLCertificate|array|string $privKey,
    OpenSSLCertificate|string $userCert,
    array $caCerts,
    string $name,
    string $passphrase
) {
    $pId = uniqid();
    $filePathKey = '/tmp/'.$pId.'.key';
    $filePathCrt = '/tmp/'.$pId.'.crt';
    $filePathP12 = '/tmp/'.$pId.'.p12';
    $filePathCaCerts = '/tmp/'.$pId.'.crts';
    openssl_pkey_export_to_file($privKey, $filePathKey, null);
    openssl_x509_export_to_file($userCert, $filePathCrt);
    file_put_contents($filePathCaCerts, implode("\n", $caCerts));
    if(system(
        '/usr/bin/openssl pkcs12 -export -legacy'
        .' -inkey '.$filePathKey
        .' -in '.$filePathCrt
        .' -out '.$filePathP12
        .' -certfile '.$filePathCaCerts
        .' -name '.escapeshellarg($name)
        .' -password '.escapeshellarg('pass:'.$passphrase),
        $returnCode
    ) === false) {
        throw new \RuntimeException('Unable to run openssl command');
    }
    if($returnCode !== 0) {
        throw new \RuntimeException('openssl command return code is '.$returnCode);
    }
    $p12Content = file_get_contents($filePathP12);
    unlink($filePathKey);
    unlink($filePathCrt);
    unlink($filePathP12);
    unlink($filePathCaCerts);
    return $p12Content;
}


Yeah, I know, I'm also using this approach, but I'm not comfortable with enabling functions like system/proc_open and so on. I've added a feature request in php-src repo.
